# Math symbol for positive correlation

Tags: statistics, notation, correlation

I want to represent in a math formula the positive correlation between two variables. For instance, how could you express the positive correlation between $x$ and $y$, where $x$ is the amount of minutes a student studies for a test, and $y$, the grade obtained on the test?

Comment: That's assuming there's a correlation at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function

Comment: Check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence). Three most popular metrics are Pearson's $r_{X, Y}$, Spearman's $\rho_{X, Y}$, and Kendall's $\tau_{X, Y}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has the only reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible options.

Assume $y = f(x)$ then you can say that $y$ is positively correlated with $x$ if $f'(x) > 0$.

Without resorting to a $f$, you can equivalently write $corr(x, y) > 0$.

Comment: Just curious, why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ used instead of $\frac{d f}{d x}$ here if $f$ is in one variable?

Comment: ah! I don't know. Now that I see it again, I guess $f'(x)$ would be even better. Do you think it is problematic to the point that I should edit my answer?

Comment: Perhaps $f'(x)$ would be more of a concise notation. Edit your answer as you please :)